# onItemAtEndLoaded is called immediately after onZeroItemsLoaded

Tags: android-jetpack, android-paging

I have a problem where the method `onItemAtEndLoaded` is called **immediately after** `onZeroItemsLoaded`, the behavior should be only when I finish the scroll. Do you have any idea of what is happening. I can provide my GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by setting **PrefetchDistance to zero** in `PagedListConfig`

```
PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPrefetchDistance(0) // solved
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(pageSize)
                .setPageSize(pageSize)
```

Comment: hi, it seems to me as the correct answer, I read in the documentation too, as I understand these arguments here.
though now onItemAtEndLoaded never gets called now after changing into this.

Comment: Which data source are you using?

Comment: Thanks Malmaison for replying, DataSource.factory< int, my class>

Comment: I use the Google codelab for learning and implementing this, mithun search one, their search api take page_no and limit while mine takes an offsetId ( fetch item with higher id ) and limit

Comment: Actually, this thought has come to my mind that it being not working might have to do with the type of data source

Comment: I am not sure at the moment. I will check it out for you.

Comment: hey it worked, actually, I did a mistake, my adapter was still extending ListAdapter instead of PagedListAdapter.
I am another problem, how to tell BoundryCallBack that it has to fetch all from the network.
My app is crashing when it gets 0 items.